# Shift register 5V VCC and data while 3v3 serial?

Tags: shift-register

I want to use 5V for VCC and data pins for shift registers (HC595 and HC165) with a common GND while using 3V3 clock, I haven't tested yet. But is it okay to do that ? or it will reduce IC life span ?

The reason of using 5V is that, I do not want to put load on microcontroller and want to directly connect multiple shift registers using an external supply.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question: using 5 V Vcc and 3.3 data and clock will not damage your shift registers, but may result in unreliable operation, if the 3.3 volt signals don't meet the Logic High spec for the shift registers.  You can avoid this problem by using the 74HCT (TTL-compatible) versions of the shift registers, as they have lower Input High thresholds.

I don't understand your concern about putting a load on the microcontroller if you use a 3.3 volt supply.  If you have an available 5 volt supply, you can use a 3.3 volt regulator from that supply to provide 3.3 volts to your shift register, if you are concerned about overloading a 3.3 volt regulator on you microprocessor board.

Answer (score 1):

Use parts that say "T" in the middle.  That is: 74HCT595 & 74HCT165.

The "T" in the middle of the part number means that the chip has TTL threshold levels.  A logic 0 is a voltage less than 0.8V, a logic 1 is a voltage greater than 2.4V.  Your 3.3V device will work just fine with those chips.

Note: be sure to connect the ground terminals of your power supplies together.